# Spring Error - Handler Method not Found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I have problem in calling the controller. The server returns did not find handler method error. Following is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>  

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>1000</param-value><!-- 10000 -->
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    
</web-app>
```

The following is my servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.til.et" />
    <default-servlet-handler />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" /> 

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/rest/jsp directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/rest/jsp/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

And following is my controller

```
    package com.et.til.mynewsletters.admin.controller;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


    @Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
        public String hello(HttpServletRequest request) {

            return "Hello";
        }
    }
```

The /hello mapping is not working inspite of url pattern in the dispatcher servlet being "/". The tomcat server returns Handler method not found and there is no error or exception in the tomcat logs. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try correcting `<context:component-scan base-package="com.til.et" />` to  `<context:component-scan base-package="com.te.til" />`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you deployed it on a sub-context in tomcat. E.g., if your war file is called "my-project.war", your handler method needs to be accessed at http://localhost:8080/my-project/hello

Comment: I deployed war as my-project.war and accessing the controller from http://localhost:8080/my-project/hello only. Despite that it is not working.